# FlaggedRevs requires running .../mediawiki/maintenance/update.php from command line

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

[image]What is required to run it? Because if it is run from browser address line it gives a message

> This script must be run from the command line

What does it mean?

After I do this stuff in windows command line:

```
C:Program Files>cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mediawiki\maintenance

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mediawiki\maintenance>update.php
```

it just opens the file,

don't know much about command line and how to use it.

got this after been suggested to do it through php.exe

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to run it using `php.exe`. If you have it in your PATH, you can use just:

```
php update.php
```

If you don't have it in PATH, you need to specify the whole path yourself:

```
C:\path\to\php update.php
```

Comment: ok, does it actually matters if the file that I need to run located in mediawiki folder, where as php.exe located at different location.

Comment: question if I am running it on windows machine do I need to choose php-cgi.exe ?